# How can I calculate the optimal way to divide an area into specific sized pieces?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for a way, through R, to optimize cut lengths and widths for materials.

I am looking for a way to optimize material used in orders. For example, let's say the following are rolls of Material A in stock (length and width):

```
1,450.000 ft X 16.750 in
1,350.000 ft X 8.500 in
330.000 ft X 4.625 in
250.000 ft X 4.250 in
100.000 ft X 2.750 in
460.000 ft X 2.625 in
```

Someone places an order for Material A, and they want the following rolls (length and width):

```
500 ft X 0.489 in
833.33 ft X 0.505 in
400 ft X 0.412 in
845 ft X 0.6 in
1000 ft X 0.629 in.
```

How can I determine the optimal series of cuts that would result in the least possible waste?

(The example given is relatively simple, and could even be done by hand, but there are actually hundreds of in-stock materials and hundreds of orders).
I have tried software such as Cutlogic, but would prefer to use R.

Comment: For some approaches see [Sheithauer, Introduction to Cutting and Packing Optimization](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Cutting-Packing-Optimization-International-dp-3319644025/dp/3319644025)

Comment: Thanks, Erwin, that's a super-interesting reference, and one I didn't know of. Unfortunately, my library doesn't own a copy. Appears that 2D cutting problems can be formulated as linear programs -- is that correct?